# Duplicate keys under app.config

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, connection-string, app-config

I have a project where I maintain separate app.config files for connection strings for each environment, for example, a Dev.config for the dev env, QA.config for QA, etc. I have a master app.config file where I just key in the env as "Dev" or "QA" and the env specific connection strings are activated as shown below.

Dev.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="connection1" connectionString="<dev_string>" />
   <add name="connection2" connectionString="<dev_string>"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

QA.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="connection1" connectionString="<qa_string>" />
   <add name="connection2" connectionString="<qa_string>"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

App.config

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings\Dev.config">
</connectionStrings>
```

But, now I have a reqmt. where cross-environment functionality is to be implemented. What is the best approach to go about this? I could add each of the connection strings in the master app.config by giving it an env specific name, but I feel this might not be the best approach.

So, is there a way to still keep the env specific config files and load all the connection strings across all environments in the master app.config under different namespaces or something to avoid key duplication errors?

Thanks in advance for all the help...

Comment: Odd requirement

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right I may recommend you to use default xdt:Transform syntax like in Web.Config/Debug/Release. For app.config files you can use something like this package https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7bc82ddf-e51b-4bb4-942f-d76526a922a0

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure if this will work out for me. I am looking for a way to access connectionstrings of all environments in code, with the same keys "connection1" and "connection2"; maybe using a namespace like dev.connection1 or qa.connection1. At the same time I would like to have ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection1"] point to the specific environment that is set in the config. Is this possible?